# How to make AppCompatImageView works in widget?

Tags: android, widget, android-imageview, android-appcompat, androidx

I try to use AppCompatImageView to display a vector image in a widget, but image is not displayed (instead I got a cut message "Error loading..."). The same piece of code works well in my main activity (both are in LinearLayout). Is there a limitation for widgets ? What do I miss ?

My minSdkVersion is 19, and I use androidx.

I tried to change layout to a standard LinearLayout.

My XML :

```html
<androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/widget_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_image"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:contentDescription="@+id/appwidget_label"
        android:padding="5dp"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_baseline_toggle_off_24px"
        android:tint="@color/colorAccent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/appwidget_label"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:paddingLeft="2dp"
        android:paddingRight="2dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@string/appwidget_default_text"
        android:textAlignment="gravity"
        android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

</androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
```

Extract of my build.gradle :

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat-resources:1.1.0-alpha05'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.0.1'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.10.0'
    implementation 'de.greenrobot:eventbus:2.4.0'
    implementation 'com.j256.ormlite:ormlite-android:4.48'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.0.1'
}
```

Some messages in logcat I don't understand (but not necessary related to my problem) :

```
05-21 19:38:09.886 12404-12404/com.yadoms.widgets.statedisplay E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
05-21 19:38:09.886 12404-12404/com.yadoms.widgets.statedisplay W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve instanceof 216 (Landroid/graphics/drawable/RippleDrawable;) in Landroidx/appcompat/widget/AppCompatImageHelper;

05-21 19:38:09.906 12404-12404/com.yadoms.widgets.statedisplay E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.view.textclassifier.TextClassificationManager', referenced from method androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextClassifierHelper.getTextClassifier

05-21 19:38:10.066 12404-12404/com.yadoms.widgets.statedisplay E/EGL_emulation: tid 12404: eglSurfaceAttrib(1199): error 0x3009 (EGL_BAD_MATCH)
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a limitation for widgets ?

Yes. You are limited to the roster of widgets [listed in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html#CreatingLayout).

In particular, you cannot use any custom widgets, either your own or from libraries (e.g., AndroidX). That is because your app is not rendering the app widget — the home screen is.

Comment: Thanks. I though that as ImageView is authorized for widget, AppCompatImageView will be too. But I didn't see the mention "Descendants of these classes are not supported.", and AppCompatImageView  is decendant of ImageView. :-(